# Flash Action Script 3 design custom MovieClip as Button

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am new to Flash AS3.I am trying to create a movie clip which should behave as button.
See image below for reference.

I want to know how can i create a package for this custom button so i can create as many buttons as i need with this package by specifying (name,image) in argument.

```
Main movieclip mc_btn
   -- has submovieclip mc_txt
   -- has submovieclip mc_img
//mc_btn changes color from black to any-other color when on hover ..
```

I don't know if i need mc_txt or mc_img. Any suggestion is welcome as I am new to this thing.

[image]

**Code I came up with: But still i am unable to add external image**

```
// mc_main
var mc_main:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
//mc.graphics.lineStyle(1,0x0000CC);  
mc_main.graphics.beginFill(0x0000CC);
mc_main.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 400, 40);
mc_main.graphics.endFill();
mc_main.x = 80;
mc_main.y = 60;
addChild(mc_main);

//mc_txt
var mc_txt:TextField = new TextField();
mc_main.addChild(mc_txt);
mc_txt.text = 'Hello!';
mc_txt.x = 50;
mc_txt.y = 8;
//mc_txt Color
var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
tf.size = 18;
tf.bold = true;
tf.font = "Arial"
tf.color = 0xFFFFFF;
mc_txt.setTextFormat(tf);
```

Comment: The code provided works? But you just want to create a Class (not a package) out of it?

Comment: In above code , i was unable to add image yet. How can i add image , preferably not from library but external Image .And yes, i want to create a package so i can keep adding buttons like ```new button ("title","image url")```

Comment: You can use a `Loader()` to load images dynamically.

Comment: can you provide with loader code for above exampel.Thankx

Comment: ok.got it.Now onto creating package ..